Generate the Authorization Code - Redirecting to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/undefined
I have google OAUTH2.0 cliend id setup as below
Origins
http://localhost:3000
https://icy-..-0--f03.5.azurestaticapps.net
https://l..nd-fu..ons.azurewebsites.net

Redirect URIs
http://localhost:3000
https://icy-..-0--f03.5.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/google/callback
https://l..nd-fu..ons.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google/callback
https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback
https://l..nd-fu..ons.azurewebsites.net

Overview of my goal: Static web app (react) - authenticate to google (simple )
and then use function app secured using the same google oauth2.
Status:
Step 1: React app deployed as static webapp and login works.
Step 2: Function app with a small hello world function with identity provider (google) configured.  I am trying to test using browser
Problems:
unable to test the function independently using postman or function apps "Code + test"
So try to test using browser/firefox to -> Generate the Authorization Code
Process:

using redirect to function app..pasted the below in browser and authenticated
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=11...4...uboamu.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://l..nd-fu..ons.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google/callback&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email%20profile


OUTPUT i.e. landing on : https://l..nd-fu..ons.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/done

using redirect to static web app ( assuming we start from webapp)..pasted the below in browser and authenticated
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=11...4...uboamu.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://icy-..f03.5.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/google/callback&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email%20profile


OUTPUT i.e. landing on : https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/undefined
what is this...https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/undefined
why it is landing there ?
(When working from React, we are not supplying redirect_uri. react-oauth/google@latest must be doing the magic with client_id.)
so what is happening under the hood? Any configuration required on static web app or ignore ? I want to make application testable.
Please advice. Thanks

Are trying this azure function app /share the details where exactly you are facing the issue.

Please vsee "step2". the function is non-anonymus and returns a Hello World. I have moved away from this design, as I dont have any trust or cost viable.

use https://icy-..-f03.5.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/google/callback to  login

to configure rediect use  Routes like this in staticwebapp.config.json
  "routes": [
      {
          "route": "/routeTypedIntoBrowser",
          "redirect": "/redirectToMe",
          "statusCode": 301
      }
  ]
}``` refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration)

ues like this "routes": [     {       "route": "/",       "rewrite": "/index.html"     },     {       "route": "/.auth/login/google/callback",       "allowedRoles": ["authenticated"]     },
