Axios - React SWA - Azure function app - message: "Request failed with status code 400", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
I am looking for a way to secure my Azure function app API.
The Static WebApp is react based and has google oauth.
I have simple functions that work from Code + Test , before linking Static WebApp and Function App.
After linking the expectation is to deny unauthorized access. But getting error {"code":400,"message":"Login not supported for provider azureStaticWebApps }
Config in azure portal

Error: (firefox console)

​ message: "Request failed with status code 400", name: "AxiosError",
code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest,
response: {…}, status: 400 } code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"

Network tab of developer tools (firefox)

{"code":400,"message":"Login not supported for provider
azureStaticWebApps"}

Dev and Integration:
Created a react app, implemented google oauth , axios api.
   async function getItems( formattedDate, category,  personal, token) {
  try {
      const response = await instance
    .get("/api/register/find", {
          headers: { 'Authorization': bearer(token) },
          params: {        
            incidentDate: formattedDate,
            category: category,
            personal: personal
          },
        });
          return response;
        }
        catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        };
    }

function bearer(token) {
return Bearer ${token};
}
Function code :
@FunctionName("findRegister")
public HttpResponseMessage find(
        @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET}, route = "register/find") HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
        final ExecutionContext context) {
    context.getLogger().info("Processing /register/find endpoint");
    final String query = request.getQueryParameters().get("incidentDate");
    final String incidentDate = request.getBody().orElse(query);
    var itemDto = new ItemDto(…);//dummy output
    var response = new ArrayList<ItemDto>();
    response.add(itemDto);
    try {
        String jsonResponse = mapper.writeValueAsString(response);
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .body(jsonResponse)
                .build();
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        context.getLogger().severe("Error creating Items : " + e.getMessage());
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .body("Error Fetching response")
                .build();
    }

}

Function app is not logging - context.getLogger().info("Processing /register/find endpoint"); Not sure why ?
There is some info about a file   staticwebapp.config.json from link - info link
but not sure where this exists. (could not find)
Should SWA be created differently? configure SWA
How to troubleshoot ? Is there a way to test or remote debug ? Is there a problem in the request ? Anything react app config to check
As mentioned before I dont have staticwebapp.config.json...not sure if azure-static-web-apps-icy-dune-09764cf03.yml is alternate
How to test function app in Code + Test  after linking ?


Are you fetching data from a secure function API in the backend to the frontend static web app?

If possible, share your complete GitHub repository?

As mentioned in the post, there is a function @FunctionName("findRegister") that is not anonymous and returns a hard coded value (to start). A provider(google) was added. Test using Code + Test . This is the scenario. hope it is clear

@Kris Swat  have you added staticwebapp.config.json: {
"routes": [
{
"route": "/api/*",
"allowedRoles": ["authenticated"]
}
]
}    refer to link for Login with Google oauth in  React app

@Sampath we are testing a function and then test from web app. we can think about /api/* end points after Code + Test function works. For info I tried that json also.

Can please share same json out put of post request and what input are giving as well for post request. Please don't Miss any input parameters and where you get parameters from as well and out as well.

Is it possible for you to take a function "hello" make it non-anonymous. configure google identity and check? my function is also basic.

I am using java. may be it makes no difference ( c#/py/js).

After deploying the sample Azure Function, I enabled Google authentication but encountered the same 401 error, as shown below:


You need to  use the URL https://<app-name>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google/callback for login purposes:


I referred to this guide for adding Google login to a React app. In the React app, I used the callback URL code as shown in this documentation.

Below code is Google login with  the React app using callbackurl:
const handleClick = () => {
    const callbackUrl = `${window.location.origin}`;
    const googleClientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FROM_GOOGLE";
    const targetUrl = `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(
      callbackUrl
    )}&response_type=token&client_id=${googleClientId}&scope=openid%20email%20profile`;
    window.location.href = targetUrl;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const accessTokenRegex = /access_token=([^&]+)/;
    const isMatch = window.location.href.match(accessTokenRegex);

To fetch the data, I used the following code:
   if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error: ${res.status} - ${res.statusText}`);
      }
      const data = await res.text(); // Assuming response is plain text.
      setResponse(data);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

I followed this doc for Google Authentication with my Azure Function app. Additionally, I referred to this Microsoft documentation for enabling Google authentication in Azure Static Web Apps.
Here’s the staticwebapp.config.json file configuration:
staticwebapp.config.json:
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/",
      "allowedRoles": ["anonymous"]
    }
  ],
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html"
  },
  "globalHeaders": {
    "cache-control": "no-store, must-revalidate"
  },
  "trailingSlash": "auto",
  "auth": {
    "identityProviders": {
      "google": {
        "registration": {
          "clientIdSettingName": "GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID",
          "clientSecretSettingName": "GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Make sure to add CORS settings in the Azure function configuration.


I appreciate your efforts. Would be great if you create how to page in microsoft. I used simple mechanism i.e. google login component and may be got similar thing working, but I want fully testable code, i.e. function should be testable from Code + Test. At this moment I am out of credits in Azure , courtesy API management has eaten £5 per day, as I was not aware of its costs. For info, I also tried from browser to get "you have successfully signed in", but not desired. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79166604/generate-the-authorization-code-redirecting-to-https-login-microsoftonline-c

I will read the answer, apply and then will mark as accepted, if it works. ( after I get some azure credits) thank you
